# Suggestion/Guidance to Implementing LDAP (Active Directory) authentication

Tags: ldap, shiro, spring-ldap

**Problem Statement:**

I am trying to build a custom management system which would require authentication and authorization both. 
The system needs to have capabilities to manage/create/update/delete users, roles, permissions and groups.

**My Design Solution**

I am planing to implement this in-house from scratch and would provide authentication and authorization as follows.

Authentication : user would provide their credentials and the system would authenticate if the user is valid or not.

Authorization: once the user is authenticated, based on the user groups and the permissions they could access the requested pages on the site.

**Question:**

Now, my question is that suppose I have this application built successfully and in future my application requires LDAP (active directory) authentication would it be possible to plug in LDAP related features keeping my existing application intact or I would have to re-write the entire or most application using LDAP API's.

I have had a look at at apache shiro and spring security which
provides LDAP functionality and they also provide capabilities to manage/create/update/delete users.

As of now I have not yet decided if I would go with either of them or write my own.

Would appreciate if I could get a detailed reponse about how to go about things.

**Note:** 
I am a complete newbie to LDAP so please excuse me if I have used some wrong terminology with regards to LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is a serious domain, with lots and lots of hidden complications. I would definitely recommend against implementing this yourself. Since you mention Spring LDAP, I'm guessing you're in a Spring-based project. The obvious choice in such a setup would be the excellent [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) project.

Comment: thanks, does spring security has the capability to allow/disallow access to a certain page based on the permissions and roles ? Can I define groups in my table and let spring use these groups to allow/disallow access to a certain page ? Can I define custom roles in spring security ?

Comment: Oh yes, all that and much more :). Spring Security uses role-based security authorization by default. It's not clear from your question what you mean to achieve by separating roles, permissions, and groups (are you thinking about ACL-based authorization?), but everything is fully pluggable so you will be able to use any custom authorization scheme you might want (there's out-of-the-box support for ACL-based authorization as well). Check out the reference documentation, it's really good!

Comment: what I mean is that in the spring documentation it says that the authorization is based on roles. I would like to override that and create authorization based on permissions. I would have 3 tables in my schema. user, roles and permissions and i would like to authorize users by permissions and not by roles. Its like if a user has a specific permission do a certain action or show a certain page else do not. So its kind of having my own user, permissions and roles table and using spring security. Also I would have a User Interface to edit, update, and create new roles, users and permissions.

Comment: In its simplest setup, authorization in Spring Security is based on something called a Granted Authority. In the out-of-the-box implementation this is typically roles, but this is completely pluggable; all you need to do is tweak the Granted Authority population for each user based on your specific needs (in your case, populate with permissions instead). User interface (and back-end infrastructure) for editing/updating etc. is completely separate from the authentication/authorization infrastructure. Spring-ldap is a useful tool for simplifying the back-end part of this.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend NOT implementing this your self, just integrate with existing API.

Disclosure: I work for [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) (which provides exactly this) and on [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).

Also, if your application needs to be backed by LDAP, *most* LDAP setups I've seen only support read operations when integrating with applications, so you may want to chat with your LDAP admin and see if your 'manage' user use case is viable.

Comment: does spring security or apache shiro has the capability to support custom roles, permissions and groups ? Can i control access to a specific page for a user based on his permissions not roles in spring security or Shiro ?

Comment: Yes, a general overview on [Shiro's permissions](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html) which in turn can be configured to protect a given [path](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-WebINIconfiguration), or via programatic and annotation based approaches.